# How to use window.onscroll with Mobile Browser

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to use jquery to detect when the user scrolls to the end of the browser window. I am adding a css class to it's following `div` so that I can control it to `display: block;`. It's working on every browser on PC but it's doesn't work on mobile's browser.

Here is the script below:

```
window.onscroll = scroll;
var count = 2;

function scroll() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
    //if ((document.body.scrollHeight - document.body.offsetHeight) == window.pageYOffset)
    {
        $(".ads-block" + count).addClass("block");
        count++;
    }
}
```

Anyone know what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

On mobile devices you can use touchmove for this problem. Something like :

```
$('window').on('touchmove', scroll);
```